# Recode Variable in R after matching with another Data Frame

Tags: r

I have 2 dataframes in R,

DF1

```
|attr1|attr2|attr3|
|5    |4    |9    |
|4    |30   |2    |
|5    |18   |1    |
|3    |1    |7    |
|6    |30   |0    |
|8    |18   |12   |
```

Now, i'm trying to recode the values present within the attr2 column in this dataframe in a manner such that if the value in attr2 is present within the col1 in DF2 then it should be recoded as 1 otherwise as 0. The second dataframe is simply a count of the top 2 unique values within attr2

DF2

```
|Var1|Freq|
|30  |2   |
|18  |2   |
```

I want the result to be in the format of something as follows:

```
|attr1|attr2|attr3|
|5    |0    |9    |
|4    |1    |2    |
|5    |1    |1    |
|3    |0    |7    |
|6    |1    |0    |
|8    |1    |12   |
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: `df$attr2 <- df$attr2 %in% DF2$Var1`

Comment: In addition to the above one, as i want it to be coded as 0 or 1, 
' df$attr2 <- ifelse(df$attr2 %in% DF2$Var1,1,0) '

Answer (score 0):

We can use

```
library(dplyr)
DF1 %>%
     mutate(attr2 = as.integer(attr2 %in% DF2$Var1))
```